# request with multiple columns Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wanna request a column so I can remove it. This is the table(SerialNumber) layout:

- id
- product_revision_id
- booking_id
- serial_nr

Now do I have the booking_id and the product_revision_id values and thats is how I wanna select them.

like this:

```
SELECT* FROM SerialNumber WHERE booking_id = '123456' AND product_revision_id = '987456'
```

but then like this:

```
 $serial_nr = $em->getRepository("KopictAdminBundle:SerialNumber")->find();
```

Can some one point me in the right direction?

**--------------Requested edit--------------------**

```
class SerialNumber
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var interger $product_revision_id
     */
    private $product_revision_id;

    /**
     * @var interger $booking_id
     */
    private $booking_id;

    /**
     * @var string $serial_nr
     */
    public $serial_nr;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product_revision_id
     *
     * @param integer $product_revision_id
     * @return SerialNumber
     */
    public function setProduct_revision_id($product_revision_id)
    {
        $this->product_revision_id = $product_revision_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product_revision_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getProduct_revision_id()
    {
        return $this->product_revision_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set booking_id
     *
     * @param integer $booking_id
     * @return SerialNumber
     */
    public function setBooking_id($booking_id)
    {
        $this->booking_id = $booking_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get booking_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBooking_id()
    {
        return $this->booking_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set serial_nr
     *
     * @param string $serial_nr
     * @return SerialNumber
     */
    public function setSerial_nr($serial_nr)
    {
        $this->serial_nr = $serial_nr;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get serial_nr
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSerial_nr()
    {
        return $this->serial_nr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer with your SerialNumber entity ? And I'll can help you

Answer (score 2):

In your SerialNumberRepository.php:

```
/.../

public function findByBookingAndProduct($idBooking, $idProduct)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->where('s.booking_id = :booking_id')
        ->andWhere('s.product_revision_id = :product_id')
        ->setParameter('booking_id', $idBooking)
        ->setParameter('product_id', $idProduct)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

---

EDIT: If you only want to catch the serialnumber:

```
public function findByBookingAndProduct($idBooking, $idProduct)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s.serial_nr')
        ->where('s.booking_id = :booking_id')
        ->andWhere('s.product_revision_id = :product_id')
        ->setParameter('booking_id', $idBooking)
        ->setParameter('product_id', $idProduct)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

---

And in your controller:

```
/.../

$serial_nr = $em->getRepository("KopictAdminBundle:SerialNumber")->findByBookingAndProduct("123456", "987654");

/.../
```

You also have to declare your repository in your entity :

```
/**
 * SerialNumber
 *
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\SerialNumberRepository")
 */
class SerialNumber {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does the Querybuilder know that 's' stands for SerialNumber?

Comment: `s` is for the Object: SerialNumber Entity in this case.

Comment: You can put everything you want to replace the 's'. It's just an alias for the entity that the repository act on.

Comment: "How does the Querybuilder know that 's' stands for SerialNumber?" Because it was created using a method belonging to the repository for SerialNumber.

Comment: It giving me an error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null

Comment: It giving me an error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null